# Determining whether a node is contained within another node in XSLT

Tags: xslt, containment

Is it possible to tell whether a node is contained within (or equal to) another node in XSLT?  For example, consider this code snippet:

```
<xsl:variable name="itemSection" select=".."/>
<xsl:for-each select="key('enemyItems', @key)">
    <xsl:variable name="enemyList" select="./attributes/@value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="enemyListSection" select="../../.."/>
                      .
                      .
                      .
</xsl:for-each>
```

Is it possible to tell whether itemSection is contained within (or equal to) enemyListSection?

Comment: check for Dimitre correct answer. I've missed the "(or equal to)" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath 1.0

```
$itemSection[ancestor::*[generate-id()=generate-id($enemyListSection)]]
```

In XPath 2.0

```
$itemSection[ancestor::*[. is $enemyListSection]]
```

Comment: See my minor contribution to the correctness of your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Just a small adjustment to Alejandro's answer**:

**In XPath 1.0**

```
$itemSection[ancestor-or-self::*[generate-id()=generate-id($enemyListSection)]]
```

**In XPath 2.0**

```
$itemSection[ancestor-or-self::*[. is $enemyListSection]]
```

Because the original question asked:

> Is it possible to tell whether
>   itemSection is contained within (**or
>   equal to**) enemyListSection?

Comment: I've missed the important "(or equal to)". Yours is the correct answer.